# Is it possible to handle 404 errors only in ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-errors

What web.config settings should I enter so that I can handle 404 errors but not other errors. The reason I want to handle 404 errors is that sometimes I purposely enter urls for inexisting pages but which I can handle and internally redirect to the real pages. That works fine, however, I do not want to handle other pages. On the contrary, I want to load the standard "non-custom" errors so that I can identify what is wrong with the page and see the line number causing the error. But when I enable custom errors for 404, I start getting redirected to the default error page (for 500 errors) and not have a clue of what caused the error.

Alternately I would consider having a custom error page that properly displays which page and which line is causing the error. I could do that for classic ASP but I could not find how to do that for ASP.Net.

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

P.S. not sure if it makes a difference, but my test server is IIS7.5 while the one for the live website is IIS6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

> ```
> <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
>   <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
>   <error statusCode="404" path="/Errors/404.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
> </httpErrors>
> ```

Please refer to the following post:
http://tedgustaf.com/en/blog/2011/5/custom-404-and-error-pages-for-asp-net-and-static-files/

Comment: When I run it on a IIS6 based server I get an error reading "The resource cannot be found." It works fine for 404 redirects on IIS7.5 but when there is a 500 error, I only get a "500 - Internal server error." message, without any indication as to what caused the error.